# Text goes behind gradient

Tags: html, css, overflow, gradient

Im still making a reponsive menu, with scroll controls. I added a gradient on my menu, but I want to, that gradient goes in front of my links and hide them behind it. There's is [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ofjwe6jp/15/), you can test it.

There you can see my gradient CSS on my menu

```
#page .page-nav {
  background: white -webkit-linear-gradient(left, transparent 50px, red);
  background-size: 40% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
}
```

Any solutions, how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

*As far as I know,*

**You can do it** with **vendor prefixes** and it's not supported in IE (even IE 11)

Unless someone here knows a **better way to implement it**, I would **advise against** this.

```css
body {
  background: #111;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-size: 50px
}
.page-nav {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #900, #999);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -moz-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  -moz-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p class="page-nav">Sample Sample</p>
</body>
```